# How to find the index of the shortest word in a string using C#?

Tags: c#, string, indexing

Let's say I have a string and know what word I'm looking for. The word is specifically the shortest one. How do I find its index without going through every character? `String.IndexOf()` obviously won't work as the same sequence of characters can be encountered in a longer word. Is there any way around this? It would be nice to know how to do this without LINQ as well.

For example the word is "dog" and I'm looking for it in "the .. doginess, of this dog.,. is dogy.". I would get the result as 7 even though it's not 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved it myself. I used Regex, quite similar to the one above. My one looks like this:

```
string pattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9]+" + myWord + "[^a-zA-Z0-9]";
int index = Regex.Match(someString, pattern).Index;
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I'd use Regular Expressions, where `\b` means 'word boundary'. Find a match, and return the index of that match.

```
var r = new Regex("\bfoo\b");
var result = r.Match(searchString).Index;
```

Comment: Apostrophe is also counted as a word boundary, so `\bDon\b` would match the first half of `Don't`.